# jqmodal load image

Tags: image, load, jqmodal

I want to load a jpg into a jqmodal popup.

```
<a class="jqModal" href="/ash/images/image.jpg">link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">$().ready(function() {
$('#cartdialog').jqm({ajax:'@href',trigger: 'a.jqModal'});
});</script>
```

So if I link to another page, it will successfully load that page into the div #cartdialog. If I set the @href to an image, it loads a bunch of jumbled text, numbers, and symbols.

How can I just load the image into the modal?

BTW I am referencing this script http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem as well. What I did is just put an image in the html file and load it in a href with ajax. And it works perfectly.